# How to get DEVOPS Pipeline to use appsettings.Staging.json

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a YAML Pipeline that is deploying to an Azure Web App successfully. However, it seems to be using appsettings.Production.json instead of appsettings.Staging.json. What do I do to make the pipeline use appsettings.Staging.json?

I've tried lots of things, but I can't the deployment to use appsettings.Staging.json

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that place where you deploy your app has environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` set to `Staging`. Then if you have confguration like this

```
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = builder.Build();
```

it will load apsettings as you need.